# CakePHP paginate condition

Tags: cakephp

I’d like to search multiple items copied from excel. These skus are separated by empty space. Search result is always empty because each condition should be OR not AND. How can I change paginate condition from AND to OR?

Query Result

```
SELECT *, ParentProduct.id FROM parent_products AS ParentProduct WHERE 
ParentProduct.name LIKE '%na301mo%' AND ParentProduct.name LIKE '%gf001bh%' AND 
ParentProduct.name LIKE '%cc302bf%' LIMIT 10
```

Search values

na301mo gf001bh cc302bf

Controller

```
    if (empty($results)) {
        $this->paginate['conditions'] = $this->ParentProduct->resetConditions($searchStr, 'multi-skus');
        $results = $this->paginate('ParentProduct');
    }
```

Model

```
    public function resetConditions($searchStr, $opt) {
        if ($opt == ‘multi-skus’) {
            $conditions = array();
            $searchStr = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $searchStr);
            $search_terms = explode(' ', $searchStr);
            foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) {
                $conditions[] = array($this->name . '.sku LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%');
            }
        } 
    }
```

Version. 1.3x

Please advise.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change `foreach` loop inside your `resetConditions` Medhod Like below:

```
            foreach ($search_terms as $search_term) {
                $conditions['OR'][] = array($this->name . '.sku LIKE' => '%' . $search_term . '%');
            }
```

This will make sure that all Search Terms are separated by `OR` instead of `AND`